# Como pegar ip de um usuario usando php?

Tags: php, ip

Eu estou usando a função `getenv("REMOTE_ADDR")`, para pegar o `ip` dos usuários que entrar numa determinada pagina do meu site e depois eu fiz um `if` para redirecionar aquele `ip` que não for igual o da variável de `ip` permitido. Mas quando eu jogo na hospedagem ele não pega o `ip` de quem esta acessando e sim um outro `ip`.

Alguém sabe o porque ou conhece outro método?

```
<?php

    $pegar_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $ip_permitido = "ip_permitido";

    if ($pegar_ip == $ip_permitido) 
    {
       echo 'Ip Permitido!';
    } 
    else 
    { 
        header("Location: url");
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 16):

Se não estiver utilizando serviços como *CloudFlare*, *Incapsula* e nem *Sucuri*, dentre outros, você pode utilizar:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Isso irá retornar o IP do usuário, se ele estiver usando proxy irá retornar o IP do proxy que está usando, entretanto é melhor do que confiar do `X-FORWARDED-FOR`.

---

Se estiver usando *CloudFlare*:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
```

Se estiver usando *Incapsula*:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_INCAP_CLIENT_IP'];
```

Se estiver usando o *Sucuri*:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SUCURI_CLIENTIP'];
```

---

Lembre-se que é extremamente necessário recursar conexões diretas ao servidor, restringido o acesso ao site para conexões originadas destes serviços. Caso contrário, permitirá um IP Spoofing. Isso ocorre porque qualquer cabeçalho pode ser alterado ou inserido pelo cliente, neste caso ele poderia incluir um `HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP` arbitrário e enviar a requisição por fora do CloudFlare.

Neste caso, do CloudFlare, apenas autorize o acesso aos [IPs do CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/), isso impedirá que alguém se conecte diretamente ao seu servidor e especifique um `HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP` arbitrário, [pode ver um exemplo dessa configuração em especifico aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176914/php-pegando-ip-do-cloudflare-ao-inv%C3%A9s-do-ip-do-usu%C3%A1rio/176933#176933).

Answer (score 10):

A maneira mais simples de obter o endereço de IP seria usando a variável `$_SERVER`, como `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` ou `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']`. Entretanto essas 2 variáveis nem sempre retornam o IP correto do usuário/visitante, então pode-se usar outras variáveis, o melhor modo de fazer isso seria criando uma função. **Recomendo que olhe o tópico da fonte, mesmo em inglês, para ter uma explicação e ideias até melhores.**

De modo básico criando uma função simples:

```
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

> Essa função não é de autoria minha, e sim de um usuário do fórum stackoverflow em inglês, olhe a fonte.

Fonte: [Stackoverflow em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699101/get-the-client-ip-address-using-php)

Comment: é isso mesmo vlw deu certinho aki.

Comment: Essa função é bem perigosa. O `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` e o `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` são cabeçalhos enviados pelo usuário, que podem ser alterados e manipulados. Inclusive, o `X_FORWARDED_FOR` pode possuir mais um um IP separado por virgula. _Alguém comentou sobre isso na postagem original em inglês também, não com essas palavras, mas fica o aviso aqui._

Comment: @Inkeliz Correto, eu vi este aviso, por isso recomendei que dessem uma boa olhada no tópico, já que essa seria a solução mais simples em PHP, mas tem suas ressalvas