# Porque não é bom usar essa função e como eu identifico o IP do usuário então?

Tags: php, ip

```
public function get_client_ip() {
                $ipaddress = '';
                if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
                    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
                else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
                    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
                else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
                    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
                else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
                    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
                else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
                    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
                else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
                    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                else
                    $ipaddress = 'Desconhecido';

                return $ipaddress;
        }
```

Esse código não é bom porque tem problemas de segurança já vi várias vezes dizendo aqui no fórum

Como eu pego o ip entao? EM PHP

Comment: Gente que tal me ajudar?

Answer (score 5):

Porque você confia no cabeçalho enviado pelo cliente, simples assim. Isso permite que o cliente falsifique o IP, permitindo [IP Spoofing](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_spoofing).

Basicamente a regra é "Nunca confie em nenhum cabeçalho", da mesma forma que você nunca deve confiar num cookie (que também é um cabeçalho).

---

Como atacar esse código? **Você mesmo pode testar isso!**

- Servidor:

  ```
  echo 'IP deste codigo: ' . get_client_ip();
  echo PHP_EOL;
  echo 'IP real:         ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  ```
- Cliente:

  ```
  curl http://seusite.com -H "CLIENT-IP: 111.222.333.444"
  ```

O `curl` é um software para fazer requisições, o parâmetro `-H` adiciona um cabeçalho, neste caso com o nome de `CLIENT-IP` com o valor de `111.222.333.444`. *Existem vários softwares capazes de fazer isso também, o `curl` acho que é o mais usado, mas muito longe de ser único.*

---

Para "simulação" utilizei um notebook como cliente (IP é 192.168.100.196) e um desktop como servidor (IP é 192.168.100.122) que tinha o código acima, ambos em mesma rede, portanto executei:

```
curl http://192.168.100.122/iptester.php -H "CLIENT-IP: 111.222.333.444"
```

Resultado:

```
IP deste codigo: 111.222.333.444
IP real:         192.168.100.196
```

Pronto, temos um IP falso! Podemos ignorar qualquer restrição de IP! >:D

Note que sua função confia no cabeçalho enviado. Isso poderia ser ainda mais grave, porque como estamos usando `echo get_client_ip();` estando vulnerável a XSS, afinal:

```
CLIENT-IP: <script>alert('xss')</script>
```

*Isso iria ser executado no navegador, porque não há qualquer filtro.*

---

Se quiser atacar usando o próprio PHP, então também use o cURL:

```
$alvo = 'http://192.168.100.122/iptester.php';
$ipFalso = '111.222.333.444';

$curl = curl_init($alvo);

curl_setopt_array($curl, [

    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'CLIENT-IP:' . $ipFalso,
        'X-FORWARDED-FOR:' . $ipFalso,
        'X-FORWARDED:' . $ipFalso,
        'FORWARDED-FOR:' . $ipFalso,
        'FORWARDED:' . $ipFalso,
    ],

]);

curl_exec($curl);
```

Supondo que o `http://192.168.100.122/iptester.php` contenha o código de exemplo mencionado em cima. ;)

Comment: Fiquei na dúvida @Inkeliz. É preferível que eu utilize o $_SERVER então?

Comment: Sim, use o `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, exceto se você usa CloudFlare (ou outro proxy), [daí você usa os cabeçalhos oferecidos por eles](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/179389/como-pegar-ip-de-um-usuario-usando-php/179455#179455).

Comment: Este valor em `$_SERVER` é definido pelo próprio servidor, certo?

Comment: É definido pelo próprio webserver (Apache/Nginx), ele informa o IP do cliente que está acessando, a menos que esteja configurado errado. É bem mais difícil de falsificar isto do que um simples header. Existem alguns CVEs sobre casos parecidos com esse código, por exemplo do [CakePHP](http://legalhackers.com/advisories/CakePHP-IP-Spoofing-Vulnerability.txt) e existe um [CWE](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/348.html) sobre isso. Existem vários [issues no Github sobre](https://github.com/simpleinvoices/simpleinvoices/issues/137), este é um e recomendação é usar o `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

Comment: Então eu devo usar sempre `REMOTE_ADDR`, nunca outro, porque podem ser modificados com algum programa? Qual o sentido da existência dos outros então?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam, sim. O `REMOTE_ADDR` é mais confiável, porque é fornecido  pelo servidor web. Há exceções, como disse nos comentários, principalmente se utilizar algum proxy reverso, [como o CloudFlare, Incapsula ou Sucuri...](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/179389/como-pegar-ip-de-um-usuario-usando-php/179455#179455). Ignorando esses "CloudFlares", se você tem servidores de cache, que também agem como proxy, pode ser que o `REMOTE_ADDR` acabe obtendo o IP local, deste outro servidor. Mas, isso é questão da arquitetura de configuração de servidores, não do PHP especificamente.